# Initializing UIView init AFTER its superclass init?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, initialization

Looking at the a lecture slide in the Stanford iOS 9 course [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcxp1bbXbL4#t=06m36s), he is creating a new `UIView` with two initializers (one if the `UIView` was created from storyboard, and one if it was created in code). The following code is written at the bottom of that particular slide:

```
    func setup() {....}  //This contains the initialization code for the newly created UIView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {  //Initializer if the UIView was created using code.
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  //Initializer if UIView was created in storyboard
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
```

The rule is that you must initialize ALL of your own properties FIRST before you can grab an init from a superclass. So why is it that in this case he calls his superclass init `super.init` BEFORE he initializes himself `setup()`? Doesn't that contradict the following rule:

> Safety check 1 A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer.
>
> As mentioned above, the memory for an object is only considered fully initialized once the initial state of all of its stored properties is known. In order for this rule to be satisfied, a designated initializer must make sure that all its own properties are initialized before it hands off up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen all the rest of the code in this example, but the rule is only that your properties have to be initialized (i.e. the memory they occupy has to be set to some initial value) before calling `super.init()`, not that you can't run extra setup code.

You can even get away with sort of not-really-initializing your properties by either declaring your properties `lazy var`, or using `var` optionals which automatically initialize to `nil`.  You can then set them after your call to `super.init()`.

For example:

```
class Foo: UIView {
    var someSubview: UIView!  // initializes automatically to nil

    lazy var initialBackgroundColor: UIColor? = {
        return self.someSubview.backgroundColor
    }()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setup()          // do some other stuff
    }

    func setup() {
        someSubview = UIView()
        someSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        addSubview(someSubview)
    }
}
```